# To have a funny bone, meaning to have the sense of humor

Tags: idioms, phrase-request

Since ["funny bone"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/funny%20bone) may also mean an inclination to laughter or the sense of humor, what may the phrase denoting the lack of those be, collocating with the "funny bone" idiom?

For example, speaking about someone lacking the sense of humor, would it be "He has no funny bone",  or "He has his funny bone broken/missing", or "he's lost his funny bone", or what else might it be?

Comment: Never heard of the "funny bone" being used with regards to a sense of humour. It hurts.

Comment: @WeatherVane - Most interesting. I had no idea this wasn't a global usage. It's quite common in the US. See [Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/funny%20bone) as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there's any *standard* negation for "funny bone", so how you choose to play off of this idiom depends entirely on your own wit.  Certainly "to have no funny bone" *works*, but surely we can do better:

> That was a great joke, but you're not laughing! What's the matter?  **Fractured your funny bone?**
>
> I used to have a pretty good sense of humor, but **I loaned my funny-bone** to an out-of-work comedian and he never gave it back.

Give it your best shot.

Comment: +1 A very humerus response.

Comment: @StoneyB An extremely _humorous_ comment)

Comment: @StoneyB - It tickled my funny bone. (Aside to Rompey: Are you sure you don't mean [_humerus_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humerus)?)

Comment: @Rompey - Relevant, I think. If I _tickle_ my funny bone, I'm probably laughing; whereas if I _bump_ my funny bone, chances are I'm wincing in pain. Sometimes the verb helps us figure out which meaning is likely intended.